# Adobe Reader: Prevent PDF from being viewed with "enhance thin lines option"

Tags: vector-graphics, adobe-reader, pdfviewer

I have included several vector graphics in a pdf that contain small lines. When viewed with Adobe Acrobat Reader, those small lines are made artificially thickened than they should actually appear, resulting in very strange looking lines.

After some research, I found out that this is due to the "enhance thin lines option" in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Disabling this option solved the problem immediately. 
But how is it possible to set this behaviour into the PDF document, so that other people looking at the document will see it with this option disabled as well (without telling them to disable this option manually)? 
I searched the web for a long time and any solutions would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: According to [this thread](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj28_K_9dTKAhULWD4KHcZ-C6UQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.adobe.com%2Fthread%2F666344%3Fstart%3D0%26tstart%3D0&usg=AFQjCNHI-i5ozGFrIQ-cOJnmbKNEtBBeQQ&sig2=vII1nfA2p70T032pdL61CQ) you can't. It's a preference that you set in Adobe and not part of the document. I find this an amazing bug.

Comment: More frustrating is that despite the thread being **active for 10 years**, with various people providing concrete use cases for having this a document-level setting instead of a global-level setting, the response from Adobe is "WON'T FIX".

Comment: I've closed this, because, as it's currently written, it's asking a general computing question, or even if it's assumed to be in a programming context it's too broad (no specifics; no programming language; not even enough for a language agnostic outline of an approach). Something along the lines of this question could be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but it needs to be focused on a *practical programming* question (e.g. how to write a program to accomplish the task).